# I try to read tsv file in R, but it throws an error about the mismatch of elements

Tags: r

The file, where you can see how the columns is separated etc.

[image: screenshot of tsv]

In fact, the 11th line has 9 elements, so what could be the issue?

```
imdb5rows <- read.table("/data.tsv", header = TRUE, nrows = 5, fill = TRUE,
                        na.strings = "")
```

ERROR:  more columns than column names

```
tt0000010   short   Exiting the Factory La sortie de l'usine Lumière à Lyon 0   1895    \N  1   Documentary,Short
tt0000011   short   Akrobatisches Potpourri Akrobatisches Potpourri 0   1895    \N  1   Documentary,Short
tt0000012   short   The Arrival of a Train  L'arrivée d'un train à La Ciotat    0   1896    \N  1   Action,Documentary,Short
```

[UPDATE] Here is my code:

```
imdb <- read.table(file = "/data.tsv", sep = "\t", header = TRUE, na.strings = "")
```

The error:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 11 did not have 9 elements
```

Comment: You ccan use `fill = TRUE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be an issue when there are more elements in a row.  We can use `fill = TRUE`

```
imdb <- read.table(file = "/data.tsv", sep = "\t",
        header = FALSE, skip = 1, na.strings = "", fill = TRUE)
```

---

Or use `fread`  to read it faster if the data is really big

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread( "data.tsv")
```

Comment: I think it may work, but my dataset is rather big so I tried to alleviate the process by determining the classes of columns first ( reading just a few rows of the whole table). But as soon as I did it, I again got another error, which indicates that there are more columns than column names. I posted the code and the error. It's so strange, I restarted R session and after that even your code didn't work and the error popped up saying that there are more columns that col. names. Before your code just made the R kind of freeze, I guess because of the size of the file.

Comment: @use1883 in that case, you can use `skip = 1` and `header = FALSE` to not read the header and then later change the column names

Comment: Or may be you can manually check the csv to  create one more column name

Comment: I did what you told and got another weird ERROR: scan() expected 'an integer', got 'Kinetograph' . I guess some entry in a column that was classified as integer holding column has a string as value.

Comment: @use1883 that is a weird error.  Is this a normal dataset

Comment: @akran I just changed all classes to be factor, and now try to read the file, but i guess because there are so many rows it will take a long time. ( there are 6326546 rows)

Comment: @use1883 if you have many rows, try with `fread` i.e. `library(data.table); dt <- fread( "/data.tsv")`